# Error in UseMethod("grid_latin_hypercube") : no applicable method for 'grid_latin_hypercube' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Tags: r, performance, xgboost, hyperparameters

I want to tune the xgboost model using bayesian optimization by tidymodels but when defining the range of hyperparameter values ​​there is a problem. Anyone can help me??

I want specific hyperparameter combinations so i use expand.grid() function to define hyperparameter values

```r
library(visdat)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
#> Warning: package 'dials' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'parsnip' was built under R version 4.1.3
library(patchwork)
library(readxl)
library(ranger)
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 4.1.3

data <- mtcars

data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)
data$vs <- as.factor(data$vs)
data$am <- as.factor(data$am)
data$gear <- as.factor(data$gear)
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)

set.seed(123)
data.training <- data

xgboost_recipe <- 
  recipe(formula = mpg ~ ., data = data.training) %>% 
  step_novel(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) 

xgboost_spec <- 
  boost_tree(trees = tune(), min_n = tune(), tree_depth = tune(), learn_rate = tune(), 
             loss_reduction = tune(), sample_size = tune(), mtry = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("regression") %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") 

# define hyperparameter range

params <- expand.grid(
  trees = seq(500,1000,by=200),
  min_n = seq(10,40, by=10),
  tree_depth = seq(6L, 10L, by=2L),
  learn_rate = seq(0.1,1, by=0.5),
  loss_reduction = seq(0.1,1, by=0.5),
  sample_prop = seq(0.1,1, by=0.5), mtry=seq(2,7, by=1))

xgboost_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(xgboost_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(xgboost_spec) 

# resampling

set.seed(123)
resampling <- vfold_cv(data = data.training, v = 10, strata = mpg)
#> Warning: The number of observations in each quantile is below the recommended threshold of 20.
#> * Stratification will use 1 breaks instead.
#> Warning: Too little data to stratify.
#> * Resampling will be unstratified.


# Tune use bayesian optimization

doParallel::registerDoParallel()

set.seed(456) 
res <-
  tune_bayes(xgboost_workflow,
             iter = 6,
             resamples = resampling, 
             param_info = params, 
             metrics = metric_set(mae),
             control = control_bayes(verbose = TRUE, 
                                     save_pred = TRUE)
  )
#> ! There are 1728 tuning parameters and 5 grid points were requested. This is
#>   likely to cause numerical issues in the first few search iterations.
#> Error in UseMethod("grid_latin_hypercube"): no applicable method for 'grid_latin_hypercube' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I get error:

> Error in UseMethod("grid_latin_hypercube"): no applicable method for 'grid_latin_hypercube' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Comment: `grid_latin_hypercube` accepts only objects of class parameters, list, param or workflow, but not bare data frames see [here](https://github.com/tidymodels/dials/blob/252f8f61476815c1f2b33965f0f300d68de722cf/R/space_filling.R#L165)